# Library for managing sub-byte named bitfields

Tags: rust, library, serialization

When writing custom network serialization in Rust, I've come across a use case for storing and retrieving values in bitfields smaller than the `u8` available in Rust.

I wrote a library that fits my use case. It exposes an API for writing enums/data at particular bit offsets and widths and retrieving their values by "position" in the underlying storage.

One obvious limitation is the hard-coded `StorageType = u32`, limiting users to at most 32 bits. Another is the current reliance on `TryFrom`, which isn't stable yet.

Any comments and suggestions for improving the API and implementation are welcome!

**Rust Playground:** https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f9b7c3243abe4a1c27db5c7d87f557e9&version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2015

**Raw Source:**

```
//! Helpers for grouping together data in sub-byte bitfields.
#![feature(try_from)]

use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::convert::TryFrom;
use std::mem;

type StorageType = u32;

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
pub enum Error {
    DataTooLarge,
    OutOfBounds,
    WouldOverlap,
    TryFromError,
}

struct BitField {
    pos: StorageType,
    width: StorageType,
}
/// A set of bit fields
pub struct BitFieldSet {
    /// Total number of bits spanned by this set
    num_bits: usize,
    storage: StorageType, // TODO support wider types
    entries: HashMap<StorageType, BitField>,
}

impl BitFieldSet {
    pub fn new(num_bits: usize) -> Result<Self, Error> {
        let supported_bits = mem::size_of::<StorageType>() * 8;
        if num_bits > supported_bits {
            return Err(Error::OutOfBounds);
        }
        Ok(BitFieldSet {
            num_bits: supported_bits,
            storage: 0,
            entries: HashMap::new(),
        })
    }

    /// Creates an associative [BitField] entry in this [BitFieldSet]
    pub fn add(&mut self, pos: StorageType, width: StorageType) -> Result<(), Error> {
        if pos > self.num_bits as StorageType {
            return Err(Error::OutOfBounds);
        }
        self.entries.insert(pos, BitField { pos, width });
        Ok(())
    }

    /// Inserts the the data at the provided position and associates its position and width.
    pub fn insert<D: Into<StorageType>>(
        &mut self,
        pos: StorageType,
        width: StorageType,
        data: D,
    ) -> Result<StorageType, Error> {
        if pos > self.num_bits as StorageType {
            return Err(Error::OutOfBounds);
        }
        let data: StorageType = data.into();
        let data_too_large = mem::size_of::<D>() > self.num_bits;
        let data_overflow = (width + pos) > self.num_bits as StorageType;
        if data_too_large || data_overflow {
            return Err(Error::DataTooLarge);
        }
        self.storage |= data << pos;
        self.entries.insert(pos, BitField { pos, width });
        Ok(data)
    }

    pub fn get(&self, pos: StorageType) -> Option<StorageType> {
        let entry = self.entries.get(&pos)?;
        let mask = (2 as StorageType).pow(entry.width) - 1;
        let mask = mask << entry.pos;
        let value = self.storage & mask;
        let value = value >> entry.pos;
        Some(value)
    }

    pub fn get_as<T: TryFrom<StorageType>>(&self, pos: StorageType) -> Result<T, Error> {
        let value = self.get(pos).ok_or_else(|| Error::TryFromError)?;
        T::try_from(value).map_err(|_| Error::TryFromError)
    }
}

impl From<StorageType> for BitFieldSet {
    fn from(raw: StorageType) -> Self {
        let supported_bits = mem::size_of::<StorageType>() * 8;
        BitFieldSet {
            num_bits: supported_bits,
            storage: raw,
            entries: HashMap::new(),
        }
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::{BitFieldSet, Error};
    use std::convert::TryFrom;
    use StorageType;

    const PATH_TYPE_POS: StorageType = 7;
    const PROTOCOL_POS: StorageType = 2;
    const ADDRESS_TYPE_POS: StorageType = 0;

    #[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
    #[repr(u8)]
    enum PathTypes {
        Named,
        Unique,
    }

    #[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
    #[repr(u8)]
    enum AddressTypes {
        IPv4,
        IPv6,
        Domain,
    }

    #[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
    #[repr(u8)]
    enum ProtocolTypes {
        Local,
        TCP,
        UDP,
        UDT,
    }

    impl TryFrom<StorageType> for PathTypes {
        type Error = Error;

        fn try_from(value: StorageType) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
            match value {
                x if x == PathTypes::Named as StorageType => Ok(PathTypes::Named),
                x if x == PathTypes::Unique as StorageType => Ok(PathTypes::Unique),
                _other => Err(Error::TryFromError),
            }
        }
    }

    impl TryFrom<StorageType> for AddressTypes {
        type Error = Error;

        fn try_from(value: StorageType) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
            match value {
                x if x == AddressTypes::IPv4 as StorageType => Ok(AddressTypes::IPv4),
                x if x == AddressTypes::IPv6 as StorageType => Ok(AddressTypes::IPv6),
                x if x == AddressTypes::Domain as StorageType => Ok(AddressTypes::Domain),
                _other => Err(Error::TryFromError),
            }
        }
    }

    impl TryFrom<StorageType> for ProtocolTypes {
        type Error = Error;

        fn try_from(value: StorageType) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
            match value {
                x if x == ProtocolTypes::Local as StorageType => Ok(ProtocolTypes::Local),
                x if x == ProtocolTypes::TCP as StorageType => Ok(ProtocolTypes::TCP),
                x if x == ProtocolTypes::UDP as StorageType => Ok(ProtocolTypes::UDP),
                x if x == ProtocolTypes::UDT as StorageType => Ok(ProtocolTypes::UDT),
                _other => Err(Error::TryFromError),
            }
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn insertion() {
        // TODO force compiler-aware mapping of position to type stored
        let mut bfs = BitFieldSet::new(8).expect("8 bits should fit into default storage type u32");
        bfs.insert(PATH_TYPE_POS, 1, PathTypes::Unique as u8)
            .expect("Data width of 1 should fit inside expected 32 bits");
        bfs.insert(PROTOCOL_POS, 5, ProtocolTypes::UDP as u8)
            .expect("Data width of 5 should fit inside expected 32 bits");
        bfs.insert(ADDRESS_TYPE_POS, 2, AddressTypes::IPv6 as u8)
            .expect("Data width of 2 should fit inside expected 32 bits");

        assert_eq!(
            bfs.get(PATH_TYPE_POS).unwrap(),
            PathTypes::Unique as StorageType
        );
        assert_eq!(
            bfs.get_as::<PathTypes>(PATH_TYPE_POS).unwrap(),
            PathTypes::Unique
        );
        assert_eq!(
            bfs.get_as::<AddressTypes>(ADDRESS_TYPE_POS).unwrap(),
            AddressTypes::IPv6
        );
        assert_eq!(
            bfs.get_as::<ProtocolTypes>(PROTOCOL_POS).unwrap(),
            ProtocolTypes::UDP
        );
    }

    #[test]
    fn from_raw() {
        let raw: StorageType = 0b10001001;
        let mut bfs = BitFieldSet::from(raw);
        bfs.add(PATH_TYPE_POS, 1)
            .expect("Data of width 1 should fit inside expected 32 bits");
        bfs.add(PROTOCOL_POS, 5)
            .expect("Data of width 1 should fit inside expected 32 bits");
        bfs.add(ADDRESS_TYPE_POS, 2)
            .expect("Data of width 1 should fit inside expected 32 bits");

        assert_eq!(
            bfs.get(PATH_TYPE_POS).unwrap(),
            PathTypes::Unique as StorageType
        );
        assert_eq!(
            bfs.get_as::<PathTypes>(PATH_TYPE_POS).unwrap(),
            PathTypes::Unique
        );
        assert_eq!(
            bfs.get_as::<AddressTypes>(ADDRESS_TYPE_POS).unwrap(),
            AddressTypes::IPv6
        );
        assert_eq!(
            bfs.get_as::<ProtocolTypes>(PROTOCOL_POS).unwrap(),
            ProtocolTypes::UDP
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! This is a great first question; it's good that you've included the unit tests that show how it's used. I hope to see more of your contributions in future here in our community.

Answer (score 4):

All in all well-written and mostly self-explanatory code. However, there are some remarks:

## Negative tests

You already provide `WouldOverlap` as a possible error, but you don't use it in `insert` or `add`. Your tests cannot check this at the moment, as they handle perfectly valid and sane code. However, real code contains errors, and we should check that our code catches those.

For those tests, use the [`should_panic`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch11-01-writing-tests.html#checking-for-panics-with-should_panic) attribute, e.g.

```
#[test]
#[should_panic(expected = "WouldOverlap")]
fn bad_insertion() {
    let mut bfs = BitFieldSet::new(8).unwrap();
    bfs.add(PATH_TYPE_POS, 1).unwrap();
    bfs.add(PATH_TYPE_POS, 1).unwrap();
}
```

## Magic numbers are semi-evil

In `new`, you assume that every byte has `8` bits. That's true for all platforms [where Rust is supported](https://forge.rust-lang.org/platform-support.html), so it's fine, but there were some platforms where [`CHAR_BIT`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/limits) isn't `8`.

For documentation purposes, I'd suggest you give the stray `8` a name, e.g. `const BITS_PER_BYTE : usize = 8`.

## Endianess

If the code is used on both little endian and big endian architectures, the underlying `StorageType` will get filled in a different way. Keep that in mind if you allow direct access to `storage` at some point, for example with `self.storage.to_be()`.

## Misleading types

Your `pos` and `width` aren't storages. They are indices and length. Yet we call them `StorageType`. The `pos` and `width` should be independent from the underlying storage.

## Bits and bytes

You mix bits and bytes in the following line:

```
let data_too_large = mem::size_of::<D>() > self.num_bits
```

After all, `num_bits` counts bits, wheras `mem::size_of` returns bytes. We can use the mentioned constant here:

```
let data_too_large = mem::size_of::<D>() * BITS_PER_BYTE > self.num_bits;
```

## Duplicate information

`BitField` is used as a value in your hash map, but the corresponding key is always the `pos`. If there is no case where those two differ, you can probably use a `HashMap<Position, Width>` instead.

Also, you probably want to implement `add` in terms of `insert`.

## Document all public functions

Every public function should get documented.

Comment: Many thanks for the review! A follow-up question:
Re: misleading types -- what would be more appropriate types for the `pos` and `width` variables? `usize`?

Comment: @elmis any unsigned type. `usize` would be fine, but there won't be any type where you can set `usize` bits.